# How to put text on gauge activity path

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I want to put text on gauge activity path like this

[image: gauge activity]

But my gauge activity is like this

```js
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'hide', function (p, delay) {
  if (this.options.alwaysVisible) {
    return this.refresh(this.chart.series[0].data[0])
  }
  
  p.call(this, delay)
})

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        marginTop: 50
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Activity',
        style: {
            fontSize: '24px'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
      alwaysVisible: true,
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        shadow: false,
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px'
        },
        pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
        positioner: function (labelWidth) {
            return {
                x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
                y: 180
            };
        }
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: [{ // Track for Move
            outerRadius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '88%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
                .setOpacity(0.3)
                .get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }, { // Track for Exercise
            outerRadius: '87%',
            innerRadius: '63%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1])
                .setOpacity(0.3)
                .get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }, { // Track for Stand
            outerRadius: '62%',
            innerRadius: '38%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2])
                .setOpacity(0.3)
                .get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickPositions: []
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            linecap: 'round',
            stickyTracking: false,
            rounded: true
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Move',
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            radius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '88%',
            y: 80
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Exercise',
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            radius: '87%',
            innerRadius: '63%',
            y: 65
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Stand',
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
            radius: '62%',
            innerRadius: '38%',
            y: 50
        }]
    }]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
```

I want to put text on gauge activity like 1st 2nd 3rd

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uu4oLc0j/)

Comment: https://ibb.co/kGwXdG here is a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply enable data labels and arrange them adequately using `x` and `y` properties.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.style
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.x
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.y

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5v2hg81b/

Comment: I disabled tooltip in my first example. Here is the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/j1pyfooe/.

Comment: i want this percentage inside the this bar path on load

Comment: To show tooltip immediately after chart loads, you can call `tooltip.refresh()` on load event, just like you did in your wrap of the `hide` function. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9kzzta7z/.

Comment: Sir i want to show this tool tip inside the ring bar i mean on the dark blue bar did you understand